# Saving 4 inputs as 1 in rails form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I have the following form fields..

```
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]', required: true, maxlength: 1, autofocus: true %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]', required: true, maxlength: 1 %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]', required: true, maxlength: 1 %>
<%= u.password_field 'pin[]', required: true, maxlength: 1 %>
```

I have a column in my database called pin (type: `integer`) which I want to save the 4 digit pin to from these fields. They have to be in 4 different inputs for the design aesthetic but I'm having trouble saving it to the database.

So far I'm getting the error:

> no implicit conversion of Symbol into Integer

When I run the following:

```
@user.pin = params.merge([:user][:pin_1], [:user][:pin_2], [:user][:pin_3], [:user][:pin_4])
```

I've tried using `join(',')` and `split(',')` together but I can't seem to get the 4 digit, as an integer.

Any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 0):

If you do a

```
begin
     "#{params[:user][:pin_1]}#{params[:user][:pin_1]}#{params[:user][:pin_1]}#{params[:user][:pin_1]}".to_i
rescue Exception => e
    <error handling here>
end
```

That should do the trick, it's dirty but it should work. I would also do some javascript validation on the input to ensure that it is a number, not a letter.

Comment: I tried this earlier and have just tried again. Using this seems to just save it as 0 in the row... Not sure why!!

Comment: Can you put a debugger in the controller action that the form posts to and then give us the results of "pp params" in the console?

Comment: Rails Console: `"pin"=>[nil, nil, nil, nil]`

Comment: Tried `.to_s.gsub(/\"/, '\'').gsub(/[\[\]]/, '')` but no luck either.

Comment: Try putting four attr_accessors on your model. Perhaps that might help?

Comment: Gimme a gist of the model and your controller.